# CallableStatement setString - Unsupported character(s)?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a Java application decoding a UTF-8 encoded `String` received over the wire and saving it to a `varchar` column in my database (SQL Server 2000).  I am saving the record using JDBC's `CallableStatement` (calling the `setString` method to set the parameter for this column).

The problem I'm seeing is that a particular `String` has been written that contains ASCII value 0 (`NUL`).  This suggests to me that SQL server cannot represent a particular Unicode character and the JDBC driver has decided to substitute in ASCII value 0, although I may be wrong.

- Has anyone else encountered this problem?
- Is there a mechanism I can use to cause the `CallableStatement` call to fail in this situation?

Ideally I would like to guarantee that data has been saved exactly as specified, or else "fail fast".

My database character set is `Latin1_General_AS_CS`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using? Don't use Microsoft's, use jTDS or something else.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's own driver.  I will probably change it but don't want to risk any knock-on effects of doing this at the moment.

Comment: To be honest, changing from Microsoft's driver is the first thing I'd try - it has a very bad reputation - we use jTDS in our production systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using 'NVARCHAR' type in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just a WAG, but would using `.setBytes(String parameterName, byte[] x)` do trick?  The byte array would come from `myString.getBytes()`.  You might want to try using using different character sets with `getBytes()`, too.